# How to make jQuery aware of id elements in Dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: html, jquery, dynamic

I'm working on a webpage that pulls in all Active Directory groups that begin with a certain string via JSON and need to add the following html into an existing <div> tag, for each AD Group returned:

```
                            <!-- Dynamically added html-->
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js_demo_accordion-3a" aria-expanded="true">
                                        <i class="fal fa-file-medical-alt width-2 fs-xl"></i>
                                        <h2 id="group1-name-here">
                                            Group1 Name Here
                                        </h2>
                                        <span class="ml-auto">
                                            <span class="collapsed-reveal">
                                                <i class="fal fa-minus fs-xl"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="collapsed-hidden">
                                                <i class="fal fa-plus fs-xl"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="js_demo_accordion-3a" class="collapse show" data-parent="#js_demo_accordion-3" style="">
                                    <div class="card-body" id="group1-name-here-card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js_demo_accordion-3a" aria-expanded="true">
                                        <i class="fal fa-file-medical-alt width-2 fs-xl"></i>
                                        <h2 id="group2-name-here">
                                            Group2 Name Here
                                        </h2>
                                        <span class="ml-auto">
                                            <span class="collapsed-reveal">
                                                <i class="fal fa-minus fs-xl"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="collapsed-hidden">
                                                <i class="fal fa-plus fs-xl"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="js_demo_accordion-3a" class="collapse show" data-parent="#js_demo_accordion-3" style="">
                                    <div class="card-body" id="group2-name-here-card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Dynamically added html-->
```

My question is, how do I initialize the newly added element "id"'s, for example "group1-name-here" "group1-name-here-card-body", so I can address them via jQuery?

For example, I tried updating the Group name and information for the first group as follows:

```
$("#group1-name-here").text("Actual Group Name");
$("#group1-name-here-card-body").text("Group one's information");
```

but nothing happens. It seems I need to somehow tell jQuery to initialize the new element "id"'s.

All the examples I find searching online are for adding an event, such as "click" to a dynamic html element, however, I want to load a new HTML section "card" and then update the "h2" text & "card-body" text, with the current groups information, then do the same for next group and so on. No click involved.

Keep in mind I'm fairly new to jQuery, so if you could keep the syntax/code as newby readable as possible, that would be great.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help. All you contritutors are awesome!

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure it's running after the DOM is updated? If you're using AJAX to load the dynamic HTML, you need to do it in the callback function.

Comment: Can you include (at least the relevant part) of how you load the new elements.  As above, your `.text(newtext)` code is likely running too soon.  Also, make sure you don't have duplicated IDs, eg if you load multiple cards and they all have id=group1-name-here then `$("#group1-name-here")` will only find the first in the document.   There's no need to "refresh" or "initialise" jquery with new HTML.

Comment: I was loading the dynamic HTML via AJAX. I'm guessing the jQuery method ".load" will automatically initialize the element id's when loaded?

Comment: If you *want* to think of it as "initialising the element IDs" then, sure.  But it's more like "adding the IDs to the DOM", which happens whenever you change the DOM, regardless of the method.  The issue here appears to be that you're checking for new elements *before* they exist - but to confirm, we need to see the code that loads new cards in relation to the code that updates them.